# $.ajax(this) doesn't work when called by setTimeout

Tags: jquery

This is the error function of `$.ajax`.
Why can't  I delay the call to  `$.ajax(this)` ?

This works:

```
error: function (req, status, error) {
                    $.ajax(this);
                    return;
                }
```

But this doesn't

```
error: function (req, status, error) {
                    var retry = function () { $.ajax(this); };
                    setTimeout(retry, 100);
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: The `return;` in the end is redundant.

Comment: I like putting it there so that people can tell me that it is redundant.

Comment: Ohhh in that case. `return;` is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `setTimeout` callback runs in the context of the global object.
Therefore, `this` is `window`, not the AJAX settings.

You need to store `this` in a variable.